# Proving Modus Tollens with Logical Equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would you prove modus tollens is a tautology using logical equivalences?

So far, I have reduced it using implication logical equivalence, demorgan's law, and double negation and got it to the form of:

q or (p and ~q) or not p = T

From there, I can't figure out how to make it always imply T. Because I tried it distributing it, but then it became something like

(q or p) and (q or ~p) or ~p which should be become (q or p) and ~p but that doesn't result in a tautology. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$((p→q)∧¬q)→¬p\\
\equiv ((¬p∨q)∧¬q)→¬p\\
\equiv ¬((¬p∨q)∧¬q)∨¬p\\
\equiv (¬(¬p∨q)∨q)∨¬p\\
\equiv ¬(¬p∨q)∨(q∨¬p)\\
\equiv ¬(¬p∨q)∨(¬p∨q)\\
\equiv ⊤$$