# Where to stop when doing decimal division?

Tags: divisibility, approximation, decimal-expansion

We know that $\frac{1}{8} = 0.125$ via calculator; however, if I didn't have access to a calculator and wanted to find this via long division, why would I stop at 3 decimal places? Why not 2 or 4?

For context, I was working on a linear approximation problem for $\sqrt{15}$. From there, I got $L(X) = 4 - \frac{1}{8}$. In class, we're told not to use calculators, and I don't know what $1\over8$ is just by looking at it. So, I was wondering how do I find out what is $1\over8$.

EDIT: My bad, I see why we stop at 0 now.

Comment: At the third step of division, you can see the division stops.

Comment: Just looking at it, $1/8$ is $1/8$.  What more could you want?  This is a perfectly reasonable way of representing this number.  Or, since this is in your problem: $$4 - \frac{1}{8} = \frac{32}{8} - \frac{1}{8} = \frac{31}{8}. $$  Bob's your uncle.

Comment: At every step in long divison, one continues with the positive remainder from the previous step. If the previous step yielded a remainder of $0$, that's when we stop (there is no next step). Look at the three steps that yield the three digits $0.125$ and you'll see how the third step is different in this way than the first two steps.

Comment: Wel,, you could theoretically continue the long division for more decimal places, but you'd just get 0.1250000000...

Comment: How did you know when to stop in your early school years? What's different now from then?

Answer (score 2):

As  $\; 8 = 2 \times 2 \times 2$, and I suppose you know that $\frac 12 = 0.5$, then
$$
\frac 18 = \frac 12 \times \frac 12 \times \frac 12 = 0.5 \times 0.5 \times 0.5 = 0.125\,.
$$

**Edit**
Long division:

$$
\begin{array}{r}
0.125\phantom{)}   \\
8{\overline{\smash{\big)}\,1\phantom{).000}}}\\
\underline{-~\phantom{(}0\phantom{.000)}}\\
10\phantom{).00}\\ 
\underline{-~\phantom{(}8\phantom{.00)}}\\ 
20\phantom{.0)}\\
\underline{-~\phantom{(}16\phantom{.0)}}\\ 
40\phantom{.)}\\
\underline{-~\phantom{(}40\phantom{.)}}\\ 
\text{Stop at zero}\rightarrow \qquad 0\phantom{.)}\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Nice. (+1) But just to be clear, this only addresses "*I don't know what* $1\over8$ *is just by looking at it*", and not the main question, which seems to be based on some kind of early school knowledge gap.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I have no idea how to properly explain the long division part other than "you stop when it is zero". I can only offer a way to know what $\frac 18$ is by looking at it.

Comment: I have no idea either, mainly because I also have no idea what the level of the OP is (why I thought +1 was appropriate). For example, the OP has asked [about improper integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268549/13130) (2nd semester college calculus in the U.S., almost certainly taken by fewer than 10% of all U.S. college students) and about [symbolic logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4254712/13130) and about [data sets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69169284) (I looked at all these before making my 2 earlier comments here), but here asks an early school math type question.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I do have knowledge gaps in algebra, that's why I have questions.  If we stop at 0, then I would say 1/8 is 0, but that's not correct or it doesn't match the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can know what the decimal value of a fraction is "just by looking at it." Over time you get to remember values that come up regularly. And you can use values that you know to find values you don't: if asked to find $1/16$ now you would know just to divide $0.125$ by $2$. Another answer to the question of when to stop doing long division is *when you have enough digits for whatever you're doing.* If your linear approximation problem requires 4 significant digits of accuracy, stop dividing after 4 (or possibly 5) digits.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you are searching for a method to make a division without a calculator. Similar to Miscellaneous answer, in the case of $1\over8$ this is what I would do:

You can write the rational like this: $$\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{2\cdot2\cdot2} = \frac{\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}}{2}$$

This means that you need to take the mid part of a number three times, so

$$\frac{1}{2} = 0.5$$
$$\frac{0.5}{2} = 0.25$$
$$\frac{0.25}{2} = 0.125$$